# Copy retrieved info to excel/text file using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am able to scrape through a website and retrieve info which are basically html weblinks. I need to copy those links onto a excel/txt file. I have written the below code which copies the link but then removes it and copying the next weblink eventually leaving out only the last link in the iteration. Any way to resolve this.

```
driver.get("https://mylink")
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[href*=PublicInfoServlet]")


for elem in elems:
    abc=elem.get_attribute("href")
    print(abc) 

with open('Fast.txt', 'w') as myfile: # This line even if put inside the 
                                           for loop still gives the same result.
     myfile.write(abc)
```

Looks like I am not iterating properly which is causing this error.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you are using write mode 'w' use append mode 'a'

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Pavan.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Pavan I was using '**w**rite' mode instead of '**a**ppend' mode that caused the issue.